# RPC Error with Payload when using the Ropsten Test Network Faucet with MetaMask

Tags: blockchain, metamask, ropsten, testrpc-to-ropsten

I'm trying to obtain some test ether from the Ropsten Test Network with Metamask, but I keep on getting an "RPC Error with Payload", whenever I try to click on "request 1 ether from faucet". I attached a screenshot as well. I have my adblock disabled if that means a difference.
Thanks!
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think this error pops up because the balance in the faucet is 0.72 ether and you are requesting 1 ether. I noticed this low balance problem happens often at https://faucet.metamask.io/ Try getting ether from https://faucet.ropsten.be/ instead by entering your account address and it should work fine